# Splunk REST API - How to add an extra field to a saved search?

Tags: rest, splunk

I wish to create an alert which should have an additional "Selected Field" - `uri_path`. I don't know how to add the field as a "selected field". How can I do that?

This is my current code:

```
curl -k -u admin:password https://splunk.rf:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches \
  -d name=http1 \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode actions='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='0' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='4' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='uri_path' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='5m' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='greater than' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='10' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode allow_skew='0' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='*/2 * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.earliest_time='-2m' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.latest_time='now' \
  --data-urlencode search='sourcetype="auth" failed'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for is `display.events.fields`. This will add the field to "selected fields".

Here is your code, with the correct parameters:

```
curl -k -u admin:password https://splunk.rf:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches \
  -d name=http1 \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode actions='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='0' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='4' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='uri_path' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='5m' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='greater than' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='10' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode allow_skew='0' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='*/2 * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.earliest_time='-2m' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.latest_time='now' \
  --data-urlencode display.events.fields='["host","source","sourcetype","uri_path"]' \
  --data-urlencode search='sourcetype="auth" failed'
```